# Formal method to predict probability of a continuous variable

Tags: probability, modeling, quantile-regression

I am trying build a regression to model cdf, i.e to predict the probability that a continuous variable exceeds an arbitrary threshold.

I explored using quantile regression, but it seems that I have to develop a model for each quantile. Ordinal logit model also has the same limitation. I also converted the observations into quantiles, percentiles to be exact.

Is there a formal method for this kind of problem? Most of the questions of this nature on CV pertain to proportional hazard model which does not work in my case. Please guide me to the appropriate direction. Thank you.

Comment: Is there only one arbitrary threshold?

Comment: So do you want do estimate the cdf of your random variable ?

Comment: It could be any arbitrary threshold. Essentially I am trying to estimate the cdf from a regression.

Comment: Maybe some sort of logit or probit model? These models are derived from models of latent variables exceeding thresholds.

Comment: I treed the ordinal logit, but like quantile regression I have to develop a model for each threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simple starting point, try linear regression: 
\begin{aligned}
y&=\beta X+\varepsilon, \\
\varepsilon &\sim D(\theta)
\end{aligned}
where $D(\theta)$ is the distribution of $\varepsilon$ parameterized by $\theta$. This yields a conditional distribution for $y|X$, just as you asked for. For example, if $D(\theta)$ is $N(0,\sigma^2)$, then 
$$
y|X\sim N(\beta X,\sigma^2).
$$
Or more generally, you can have $\varepsilon \sim D(\theta,X)$, e.g. $\varepsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2(X))$ and so 
$$
y|X\sim N(\beta X,\sigma^2(X)).
$$
If such a model is not adequate, there are also other ways to generalize it; linear models can actually be made quite flexible.

Comment: thanks for providing that perspective. Interested in hearing your thoughts on how can it be generalized. Do you mean use a different family in glm?

Comment: @earthlink, e.g. use transformations and combinations (such as products) of $X$s for nonlinear effects while remaining within a model that is linear in coefficients.